# Get all table size from all database from last 6 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, database-administration

I'm trying to get size of all tables and size should be shown from last 6 months data below is the query which I'm using to get the results.

**Note:** Below query shows size of all tables since they got created

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB 
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.Name
```

Below is the query which I customized and tried to get results from the last 6 months but it gives size of all tables since they got created. If someone can suggest me how I can modify it in a way it only shows UsedSpaceMB from last 6 months

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB,
    t.modify_date AS ModifyDate
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.modify_date >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0)
    AND t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows, t.modify_date
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.Name, t.modify_date;
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Maybe if your database has the "Recovery Full" activated you may be able to extract that information with some sort of tool. Otherwise I would just restore a 6 months would backup and merge those selects to do that.

Comment: There is no such concept for data as `last 6 months` in SQL Server. What would it even mean? The data that has been added during last 6 months? How about data that was there earlier and was deleted? Or data that was added last week but was deleted today? If you want historical statistics, you need to gather them, daily, weekly or monthly.

Comment: @JamesZ I don't want statistics I only want to check collect the size in MBs for instance, if total data in the database is 1GB. By running that query it give me the size of let's say 500MB. We want to check if we keep last 6 months data how much we can space we can save. Because the database is growing very fast and we need to drop all data before 6 months. but before that we need to check how much size we will reduce after that.

Comment: A database does not know what is "last 6 month data". Unless you have your own column there telling that, and then you just need to calculate percentage of that data vs. the table size

Answer (score 0):

The  DATEADD() function  returns a date time (smalldatetime). Its syntax is,

```sql
DATEDADD(interval, increment (int), expression (date))
```

**sample query in you case:**

```sql
t.modify_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
```

I applied above query on `sys.objects` to filter objects with modified date is less than last 6 months It will return all the objects where modified date is from last 6 months even the `create_date` is greater. before applying filter there was 182 records after filtering it reduced to 92.

[image]

> I customized and tried to get results from the last 6 months but it gives size of all tables since they got created.

if you want tables only created in last 6 month then you have to apply filter on `create_date`.

Comment: I'm trying to get the size of all the tables in a list I don't care when It got created or modified. I just want to get size of the database in the past 6 months. For example if table 'A' total size is 1GB got created 10 years ago. I want to see if I remove all data before 6 months then how what will be remaining let's say. In the last 6 months in table 'A' there is only 100MB data. With that I will know if I remove all data before 6 months I will reduce the size of my database to 100MBs and I will save 900MBs space. @Pratik Lad